# Flatten and copy artboard to clipboard in Illustrator (like screenshot)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

In GIMP there is a feature called [Copy Visible](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-edit-copy-visible.html).  It flattens and copies all visible layers to the clipboard.

Right now I'm taking screenshots of Illustrator instead, but have to put extra care to properly crop them.

Does Illustrator have a feature like "Copy Visible"?  My search queries yielded nothing.

Comment: In what instance would *invisible* objects in Illustrator be copied? Can you explain 
 a bit more? Non-visible objects can't be selected, therefore can't be copied. But I do realize there is some locking voodoo with *groups* which sometimes causes locked or hidden objects to be part of a copy operation.

Comment: I'll rename the question, perhaps it'll make more sense

Comment: Why would a screenshot copy something that is invisible? Why would a screenshot care about illustrator settings (screenshots are done by the operating system)? Why dont you just use file save or even the legacy save for web? Why not make a artboard that fits the selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm kind of guessing here....

**Assumption:** The artwork in illustrator contains various opacities and blend modes. This makes the object *appear* a certain way on the artboard(s). But when copied to the clipboard any varying opacities/blend modes get lost.

So, I'm **guessing** what you are seeking is a method of flattening artwork on-the-fly when it is copied to the clipboard. So that what's on the clipboard *looks* the same as it does in Illustrator.

If that is indeed what you are asking....

Then **no**. There is **no method** to flatten on-the-fly when copying objects to the clipboard in Illustrator. Objects would need to be flattened directly *before* they are copied to the clipboard.

Comment: FWIW, I've been zooming to 100% and using "Snipping Tool" in Windows.  Linux and Mac have similar tools, and it does the trick.

Comment: I haven't done this is some time.. but.. you *should* be able to select your objects in Ai, use `Object > Rasterize`, `Edit > Copy`, `Edit > Undo`.  (make it an action with a hot key for speed). That will flatten and rasterize the selection, copy, then undo the flattening.